# Bokeh axis styling issue

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

In the following Bokeh chart, I want to remove the thin vertical line on the y-axis that you can see at each major tick. Each major tick should be completely white. The following code will allow you to replicate the chart:

```
from bokeh.palettes import Category20
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter, NumeralTickFormatter, DatetimeTicker

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.Series(np.cumprod(1 + np.random.normal(0, 0.01, 1000)), index=pd.bdate_range(start='2010-01-01', periods=1000))

output_file('test.html')

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', plot_width=1000, plot_height=500, y_axis_type='log')
p.title.align = 'center'
p.title.text_font = 'calibri'
p.title.text_font_size = '16pt'
p.title.text_color = 'black'

p.line(data.index, data.values, color=Category20[3][0], line_width=3)

p.xaxis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(days=['%Y-%m-%d'], months=['%B %Y'], years=["%b '%y"])
p.xaxis.axis_line_width = 5
p.xaxis.axis_line_color = 'black'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font = 'calibri'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = None

p.yaxis.major_tick_line_color = 'white'
p.yaxis.major_tick_line_width = 5
p.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None
p.yaxis.formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format='0.00')
p.yaxis.axis_line_width = 5
p.yaxis.axis_line_color = 'black'
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font = 'calibri'
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = None

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.visible = False

# p.background_fill_color = None
# p.border_fill_color = None
p.outline_line_color = None

show(p)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the tick color to `'white'` means that the ticks are still drawn, they are just drawn with the color white. Since ticks are drawn after the axis rule, you see the results with the white tick interrupting the axis. There is no user-configurable way to change the order of drawing axis elements. However, you can prevent the ticks from being drawn at all by setting the color to `None`:

```
p.yaxis.major_tick_line_color = None
```

Alternatively, you could set `major_tick_line_alpha` to zero.